# Is it possible to have CUDA 8.0 installed and still be able to use the graphics card for displaying desktop?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I always assume I thought it is possible, but I spent the whole day trying to install CUDA 8.0 from the nVidia's site, and never managed to have both X.org graphical desktop working and CUDA samples run.

It kind of make sense: if the graphics card is used for general computations (CUDA) it might not be available any more to display windows. But what if I don't do any computations at the moment; then the GPU should theoretically be able to handle actual graphics. Is it supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA support for background computation is included with nVidia proprietary drivers, at least since 2014 (possibly longer ago than that).  I run background CUDA tasks (Einstein@Home GPU tasks) 24/7 on my desktop machine, and don't see it interfering in any way with normal use of the machine for web browsing, word processing, even graphics-intensive games (Path of Exile, for one).

I don't recall doing anything special, other than having a video card that supports one or more CUDA cores and up to date nVidia drivers.

Comment: Yes. I confirm. Apparently I was just one combination missing: ignore the nVidia's drivers and install the drivers found in the `ppa:/graphics-drivers/ppa`

Comment: To clarify, you have to use the *nVidia drivers offered in Driver Manager*, not the Nouveau (free/open) graphics drivers, but you're correct in that you don't need or want to install the drivers direct from nVidia's web site.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Zeiss's answer: It is possible.

I simply assumed that installing GPU drivers that gets boundled with the CUDA toolkit straight from the nVidia's site was a natural thing to install CUDA.

**Don't install nVidias driver straight from their website**. You will get CUDA working, but never be able to use X.Org.

The inspiration came from the https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Install-Ubuntu-16-04-or-14-04-and-CUDA-8-and-7-5-for-NVIDIA-Pascal-GPU-825/ howto.